# Loop plotting in gnuplot

Tags: loops, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot around 105 files in a loop in gnuplot. 
This is what I am typing in the terminal.

```
i=0.0
n=0.052
set terminal jpeg 
load "plot.plt"
```

and here is what I have in the plot.plt

```
filename = "mean_230_1.6_A".i.".dat"
plotfile = "mean_230_1.6_A".i."jpg"
print filename." ".plotfile
set output plotfile
plot "PSD_230.dat" u 2:3 w lines , filename using 1:2:3 w yerr pt 7
set output
i=i+0.0005
if (i <= n) reread
```

however, then I execute the command. I get this error:

> "plot.plt", line 1: internal error : STRING operator applied to non-STRING type

I am not sure what to do. I used similar code before, and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using `for` loops:

```
set terminal jpeg
files  = system("ls mean*.dat")                          #stores all filenames
output = system("ls mean*.dat | sed -e 's/.dat/.jpg/'")  #stores all outputs

do for [i=1:words(files)]{
   filename = word(files,i)     #select filename number i
   plotfile = word(output,i)    #select corresponding output
   print filename." ".plotfile

   set output plotfile
   plot "PSD_230.dat" u 2:3 w lines , filename using 1:2:3 w yerr pt 7
   set output
}
```

If any of your filenames contain white spaces, change the `system` functions to:

```
files  = system("ls mean*.dat | xargs -I line echo \\\"line\\\" ")
output = system("ls mean*.dat | sed -e 's/.dat/.jpg/'" | xargs -I line echo \\\"line\\\" ")
```

---

Regarding the error you obtain you should use @allo's answer, but it is not very efficient if the filenames have different number of decimals:

```
i=0.0005
plotfile = sprintf("mean_%f.jpg", i)      # 6 decimals: mean_0.000500.jpg
plotfile = sprintf("mean_%.4f.jpg", i)    # 4 decimals: mean_0.0005.jpg

i=0.001
plotfile = sprintf("mean_%.4f.jpg", i)    # 4 decimals: mean_0.0010.jpg
plotfile = sprintf("mean_%.3f.jpg", i)    # 3 decimals: mean_0.001.jpg
```

I think, if the numbers in the filenames have 4 or less decimals, it is better to use the `%g` instead of the `%f` format specifier:

```
sprintf("mean_%g.jpg", 1)         # 0 decimals: mean_1.jpg
sprintf("mean_%g.jpg", 0.01)      # 2 decimals: mean_0.01.jpg
sprintf("mean_%g.jpg", 0.0001)    # 4 decimals: mean_0.0001.jpg
sprintf("mean_%g.jpg", 0.00001)   # 5 decimals, unwanted result: mean_1e-05.jpg
```

Comment: Hey. thank you for your answer. I do have a different number of decimals, so thank you for opening my eyes to that. however, when applying your code. I got the following error:
load "plot_1.plt"
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
ls: write error: Broken pipe

gnuplot> do for [i=1:words(files)]{
                                  ^
         "plot_1.plt", line 5: invalid complex constant

Comment: Oh, my bad. The `sed` command needs a `/` after `.jpg`, as: `sed -e 's/.dat/.jpg/'`. I fixed this in my answer :)

Comment: Thanks. That saved my day. It was really useful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're having the problem with concatenating i (float) with strings?

Try `sprintf("myfilename_%f.jpg", i)` to create the filenames.

Comment: You might want to add more format specifiers to ensure the same number of decimal places throughout the series.

Comment: Hey. thank you for your answer. But the problem is with the first line. gnuplot is unable to read the data files for some reason. and I suspect it is mainly because i have "1.6" in the name.

Comment: Yep, your minimal example: ``i=0.0;plot x t 'asdf'.i'.'asdf'``. Now use: ``i=0.0;plot x t sprintf('asdf%fasdf', i)`` and it works.